# How to check if a value is an integer or a string in jasmine.js?

Tags: jasmine

I am writing unit test using Jasmine in a web app using BackboneJS.
There are a lot of examples showing you how to check a value in this way:

```
        it("should set the id property to default value", function()
        {
            expect(this.task.get("id")).toEqual(null);
        });
```

But I can't find any example checking if an attribute whether is number or string in Javascript using Jasmine.

Is it appropriate to make a check like this?
If yes, what is the proper way to make it?

Example: I want to check if the `id` is an integer > 0. How can I make it in Jasmine?

Comment: Do you considere `"123"` as an Integer or as an String? because actually it is the String representation of an Integer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would make something like this:

```
    describe("when instantiated", function() 
    {
        it("should exhibit attributes", function () 
        {  
            .....
            expect(this.task.get("id")).toMatch(/\d{1,}/);
            .....
        });
    });
```

Comment: beware this regex will validate `"wadus12wadus"`

Comment: and to mitigate that problem, use /^\d{1,}$/

Comment: Just saying, why don't you just do `/\d+/`? Kind of excessive to use `{}` haha

Comment: Maybe this is working, but I'm trying to keep my tests human readable even for non tech mates. I would implement this into a custom matcher and then use it at the test.

Answer (score 83):

For posterity, one of the questions posed here is to test whether a value is a number. From the [jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Matching_Anything_with_<code>jasmine.any</code>):

```
expect(12).toEqual(jasmine.any(Number));
```

Comment: OP added an example: `I want to check if the id is an integer > 0`. This answer fails to check for NaN, zero, Infinity, negative and floating point numbers. In time: this might be the most overrated answer ever, judging by the number of ups.

Comment: I disagree, I think this is a good (albeit incomplete) answer, using regex in this situation seems hacky to me. To complete the answer, you could simply add the line `expect(12).toBeGreaterThan(0);`

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, I don't know what the proper way is, but I will write something like that:

```
 it("should set the id property to default value", function () {
        var id = this.task.get("id");
        expect(typeof id).toEqual('number');
        expect(id).toBeGreaterThan(0);
 });
```

Comment: typeof a decimal is 'number' i think its better to use `expect(Number.isInteger(id)).toBeTruthy();` for this specific question

Answer (score 3):

```
expect( this.task.get("id") ).toBeGreaterThan( 0 );
```

If we have in consideration that:

```
expect( 1 ).toBeGreaterThan( 0 );   // => true
expect( "1" ).toBeGreaterThan( 0 ); // => true
expect( "a" ).toBeGreaterThan( 0 ); // => false
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
it('should be integer', function()
{
    var id = this.task.get("id");

    expect(id).toEqual(jasmine.any(Number));
    expect(id).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    expect(Math.trunc(id)).toEqual(id);
});
```

If you have a number that is not an integer, truncating it should lead to a number that is different, which will cause the appropriate test failure.

If you do not have support for ES6, you can use floor instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) to check this kind of things:

```
it('should be a number', function() {
  expect(_.isNumber(this.task.get('id'))).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make sure that a result is a number.

```js
it("expect the result to be a number", () => {
    expect(5).not.toBeNaN;
});
```

While this will make sure the result not to be a number

```js
it("expect the result not to be a number", () => {
    expect('five').toBeNaN;
});
```

This makes sure that the number is greater than or equal to
zero

```js
it("expect the result to be >=0", () => {
    expect(5).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(0)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(id).toBeInstanceOf(Number)
expect(id).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```

https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html#toBeInstanceOf